# It is possible to use an expression on default values in postgres?

Tags: postgresql

I have a column which has a default value of true. In Python I could use Python's fashion to validate the value like:

```
True if x < y else False
```

I would like to set the default value of a row somehow like in Python. I've tried:

```
validity boolean default TRUE if login < current_timestamp + 24*3600  else FALSE
```

but it gives me a syntax error. Is it possible to validate like in Python or should I try another way?

Comment: No. From here [Default](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtable.html):"The DEFAULT clause assigns a default data value for the column whose column definition it appears within. The value is any variable-free expression (in particular, cross-references to other columns in the current table are not allowed). Subqueries are not allowed either. The data type of the default expression must match the data type of the column." Your best bet is a trigger on the table.

Comment: Note that `current_timestamp + 24*3600` is invalid as well, if you could use an expression like that, it would have to be `current_timestamp + interval '24 hour'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not proper SQL, but even with a `CASE` expression you couldn't have a column default like this, since `DEFAULT` expressions cannot contain column references like `login`.

You will have to create a `BEFORE INSERT` trigger that sets

```
NEW.validity := NEW.login < current_timestamp + INTERVAL '1 day';
```